# Apache Spark Submit Job API Driver State ERROR Null Pointer Exception

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark cluster deployed on windows. I'm trying to submit a simple spark job using the rest api. The job is just python code that does simple hello world sentence as follows :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
def main(args):
    print('hello world')
    return 0
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(None)
```

The url Im using to submit the job is:

http://:6066/v1/submissions/create

With the following Post Body:

```
{
    "appResource": "file:../../helloworld.py",
    "sparkProperties": {
        "spark.executor.memory": "2g",
        "spark.master": "spark://<Master IP>:7077",
        "spark.app.name": "Spark REST API - Hello world",
        "spark.driver.memory": "2g",
        "spark.eventLog.enabled": "false",
        "spark.driver.cores": "2",
        "spark.submit.deployMode": "cluster",
        "spark.driver.supervise": "true"
    },
    "clientSparkVersion": "3.3.1",
    "mainClass": "org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit",
    "environmentVariables": {
        "SPARK_ENV_LOADED": "1"
    },
    "action": "CreateSubmissionRequest",
    "appArgs": [
        "../../helloworld.py", "80"
    ]
}
```

After I run this post using postmant, I get the following response:
`

```
{
    "action": "CreateSubmissionResponse",
    "message": "Driver successfully submitted as driver-20221216112633-0005",
    "serverSparkVersion": "3.3.1",
    "submissionId": "driver-20221216112633-0005",
    "success": true
}
```

`

However when I try to get the job status using :

http://:6066/v1/submissions/status/driver-20221216112633-0005

I get the driverState: ERROR , NullPointerException as follows:

`

```
{
    "action": "SubmissionStatusResponse",
    "driverState": "ERROR",
    "message": "Exception from the cluster:\njava.lang.NullPointerException\n\torg.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.downloadUserJar(DriverRunner.scala:158)\n\torg.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.prepareAndRunDriver(DriverRunner.scala:179)\n\torg.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner$$anon$2.run(DriverRunner.scala:99)",
    "serverSparkVersion": "3.3.1",
    "submissionId": "driver-20221216112633-0005",
    "success": true,
    "workerHostPort": "10.9.8.120:56060",
    "workerId": "worker-20221216093629-<IP>-56060"
}
```

`

Not sure why Im getting this error and what it means. Can someone please point me in the right direction or help me at least  how I can trouble this farther? Thanks

I tried to submit the API request using Postman and I was expecting a FINISHED or RUNNING state since its just simple hello application

**EDIT 2022-01-12:**

I was finally able to figure out the problem. To resolve this issue basically it seems like the py\jar file as specified in the "appResource" & ""spark.jars"  needs to be accessible by all nodes in the cluster, for example if you have network path you can specify the network path in both attributes as follows:
"appResource": "file:////Servername/somefolder/HelloWorld.jar",
...
"spark.jars": "file:////Servername/someFolder/HelloWorld.jar",
...

Hope that helps and save them the time and agony I had to go through.
If anybody knows why the py\jar file has to be accessible by all nodes even though we are submitting the job to the master please help me understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should set the property deployMode to client since you are launching the dirver locally:

```
    "spark.submit.deployMode": "client",
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for trying to help. I have been stuck with this for days now and dont know what to do. I have tried the client but still got the same error ...is there anything else I can try\install\troubleshoot? I have spark running on cluster of two workers and one master. Thanks

Comment: Can someone help please?...Im stuck. Thanks